# Количество последовательностей заданной длины, XOR которых имеет заданное значение

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, битовые-операции

Представилась такая задача:
Необходимо найти количество числовых последовательностей с заданными суммой и длиной, XOR которых имеет заданное значение (т.е A1^A2^A3....^An = x; x=0)
Условно говоря, на вход подается 5 20 (5 - длина последовательности, 20 - сумма чисел последовательности), на выходе должны получить число таких последовательностей.

Comment: так у Вас должно быть три числа на входе, а также ограничение по диапазону чисел. Но в любом случае, такую задачу можно решить рекурсивно (и она будет решать полным перебором...)

Comment: Да, вы правы. У себя рассматривал значение x как 0, не подавал на вход

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Чтобы XOR дал ноль, количество единичных битов в любой позиции должно быть чётно. Т.е. сперва тупо надо решить задачу представления числа в виде суммы степеней двойки (но не нулевой), причём количество для каждой степени не более заданной длины последовательности, а если число не может быть нулём, то ещё и общее количество не меньше заданной длины. А затем для каждого разложения решаем задачу разделения полученных битов по числам.

Comment: Похоже, какой-то контест или вступительное задание, раз косяком пошли спрашивать.

Comment: Ну так второе сентября